# Show that $\nabla\cdot (fA)=\nabla f\cdot A+f\nabla\cdot A$ where $f$ is a scalar and $A$ is vector

Tags: vectors

This looks very much like the product rule to me. However, is this technically a valid answer to the question? How is it best answered

Comment: What is $A$ and $f$?

Comment: Im my point of view this does look as a scalar not a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's based on product rule.
$$\nabla\cdot(fA)=\nabla\cdot\left(f\sum_{i=1}^N A_ie_i\right)$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(fA_i)$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^N \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}A_i+f\frac{\partial A_i}{\partial x_i}\right)$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^N \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}A_i\right)+\sum_{i=1}^N\left(f\frac{\partial A_i}{\partial x_i}\right)$$
$$=\left(\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}e_i\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{i=1}^NA_ie_i\right)+f\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{\partial A_i}{\partial x_i}$$
$$=\nabla f \cdot A+f\nabla\cdot A$$